# Servlet turns off after some time

Tags: java, servlets

I have a java class which i am calling thorugh servlet .
So the java code that is called from servlet takes 1 hour to execute .
Now servlet doest wait for 1 hour it agains sends the request .

SO how to prevent this .
How to wait the servlet till the whole java code gets executed ?

Please do help

Comment: I feel that this is an unrealistic way to use servlets.  Do you expect the browser to wait for an hour to get a result?  It is fine if the servlet starts the process but it should be done asynchronously so that the user and the servlet don't have to wait that long.

Comment: This is bad design.  If your servlet is being called via HTTP you will fall foul to HTTP timeouts that average 180 seconds.

Comment: So it here any other mechanism ?

i have called that function inside a seprate thread is that ok ?

That is working but it cosist of two part there is mailing mechanism in the function . So there are two types of mail i am not understanding why the second mail is not cming .Do you have clue as to why this should be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You will find plenty of information when looking for how to implement long running or async tasks using Java EE.

As already mentioned the servlet should not block in its post or get method.
A simple approach might be to link an async job id to a HTTPSession and provide some kind of feedback/progress information when the client reloads the web page or calls your Servlet again.
Other options could be JMS or Message Driven Beans, which will require more than a servlet container in the backend (getting more in the direction of an application server).

Comment: That is working but it cosist of two part there is mailing mechanism in the function . So there are two types of mail i am not understanding why the second mail is not cming .Do you have clue as to why this should be happening ?

Comment: So the problem is maybe related to sending the e-mail. Personally i would try to enhance logging (catching Exceptions ...) and get the mail process working.